# Изменения кода регистрации wordpress, какой файл редактировать?

Tags: php, wordpress, регистрация

Я пробовал честно , искал , читал ..пробовал... но увы.. ничего не нашел путевого..
Поля для регистрации:

```
выбор1 - минор (ссылка1)
Выбор2 - прайм (ссылка2)

логин
мыло
пароль


В проверки правильности заполнения...


<?php

function getPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
    $data_fin = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data_fin;
}
$url = "Если выбрали минор то ссылка1 = Логин";  (пример ссылки http://w2.dwar.ru/user_info.php?nick=FC%20SD)
$page = getPage($url);
if(preg_match('/Ключевое слово/',$page)){
    $result = $names[] = "Если ключевое слово нашлось Регистрация разрешается";
    foreach ($names as $value) {
echo "<b>$value</b><br>";
}
}else{
    $result = $names[] = "Если ключевого слова нет Регистрация запрещается";
    foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
echo "<b>$value</b><br>";
}
}
      ?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в каком файле можно отредактировать так регистрацию ,может создать отдельный модуль? как это лучше сделать, и какая документация понадобится?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь о кастомизации формы регистрации пользователей, то официальная документация должна помочь https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

Comment: Спасибо, попробую ,отпишусь

Comment: А можно у вас еще один вопрос ? вот проблема возникла с виджетами на wp, мне нужно что б выводилось 12 их , а выводится всего то 8 , в админке вижу 12 , все как положено , на сайте 8 .. использовал вот этот код для регистрации

Comment: `if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

    register_sidebar(array(
  'name' => '1-лево',
  'before_widget' => '<div class="sb-bot"><div class="sb-top"> <div class="sb-right"><div class="sb-left"><div class="sb-rb"><div class="sb-lb"><div class="sb-rt"><div class="sb-lt">',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>'
 ));

}`

Comment: А как вы его потом выводите? Я не вижу в параметрах `id`. По идее вы должны задать в массиве что-то вроде `'id' => 'test-sidebar'`, а потом вывести сайдбар там, где вам нужно, функцией `dynamic_sidebar('test-sidebar');`. Но вообще, если вам нужна помощь по другим вопросам, лучше создавайте отдельную тему, не расстраивайте модераторов :)

Comment: Да я не хочу их расстраивать ) просто вот мне кажется одна вы и отвечаете ) а вдруг не увидите нового вопроса)))

Comment: Извините за глупость , в каком файле это всё править ? пытатся сделать ))))

Comment: В файле `functions.php` :)

Comment: Спасибо , сейчас будем что нибудь чудить )) а с этим вопроссом не подскажите мне ? [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501652/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-php-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2-wordpress-c-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)