# Как добавить отдельную php страницу в wordpress c стандартными тегами?

Tags: wordpress

Вот код страницы (clan.php)

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="content"><div class="cont-r"><div class="cont-l"><div class="cont-bot">
            <div class="grad-hack"><div class="begin"></div>

FC SD:<span style="color: green;"> <?php

function getPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
    $data_fin = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data_fin;
}
$url = "http://w2.dwar.ru/user_info.php?nick=FC%20SD";
$page = getPage($url);
if(preg_match('/online=1/',$page)){
    $result = $names[] = "Online";
    foreach ($names as $value) {
echo "<b>$value</b>";
}
}else{
    $result = $names[] = "Offline";
    foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
echo "<b>$value</b>";
}
}
      ?>    </span>

        </div>
        </div></div></div></div>
    </div>



<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Добавил её в папку с шаблоном , но при запуске её пишет ошибку ... подскажите может в function.php что то прописать нужно ? гуглил, гуглил но ничего не нагуглил ))

Comment: как запускаете?

Comment: просто через адрес страницы .. trias.cf/clan.php

Comment: возвращается ошибка пхп или 404 error? Что должно выводиться на вашей странице?

Comment: возвращается `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /virtual/trias.zzz.com.ua/clan.php on line 1` , я засунул файл с описаным кодом в папку с шаблоном, думал он будет работать так же как и page.php ,index.php.

Comment: ой ой извините , то я уже перенес без папки такая ошибка, забыл совсем , да там ошибка 404 error

Comment: а что это должна быть за страница? что вы хотите на ней выводить?

Comment: файл находится по адресу '/wp-content/themes/new2/clan.php'

Comment: Это должна быть обычная статистическая страница ... ) только с отдельным php кодом, с тем же самым дизайном что и обычные страницы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае проще поступить следующим образом:

1. Создать в админке WP в разделе "страницы" новую страницу (можно пустую) с ярлыком 'clan' (указывается в поле "постоянная ссылка" под заголовком)
2. Создать в папке с темой файл `page-clan.php` и разместить в нём код из вашего файла `clan.php` (либо просто переименуйте его)
3. Теперь по адресу [http://ваш_вордпресс_сайт/clan](http://%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/clan) будет находиться ваша кастомная страница.

Обновление для решения задачи из комментариев:

```
<?php
function getPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
    $data_fin = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data_fin;
}
$nick_names = ['Tomasch', 'FC SD', 'prickly', 'Казимира']; // пример произвольного массива ник-неймов
$length = count($nick_names);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $url = "http://w2.dwar.ru/user_info.php?nick=" . urlencode($nick_names[$i]);
    $page = getPage($url);
    if (preg_match('/online=1/',$page)) {
        echo $nick_names[$i] . ': <span style="color: green;"><b>Online</b></span><br>';
    } else {
        echo $nick_names[$i] . ': <span style="color: red;"><b>Offline</b></span><br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37109/discussion-on-answer-by-alenkins----php---wordpress).

Comment: [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507961/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-mysql-php) помогите пожалуйста))) пытаюсь доделать до ума то что вы мне помогли соорудить ))) очень нужная штучка , но сильно долго ждать загрузки страницы) буду при весьма благодарен если поможете и в этот раз)